# ImageMagick not working, and not giving error messages either

Tags: perl, unix, command-line, imagemagick

I have some Perl code I wrote for a client which, in part, resizes images using ImageMagick's `convert`.

This was done via backticks, capturing the output in this way:

```
$output = `convert foo.jpg foo.gif 2>&1`; # simplified example
```

Recently my client's hosting company made what he was told were "DNS changes", and since that date*, the command doesn't work, and not only that, there's no $output either.

Assuming something has happened like him being moved to a server which hasn't got ImageMagick, or a botched install or update of the library -- shouldn't I be getting something back from that? At least a "convert not found"? I've tried with system() as well and it's the same. Image not converted, nothing comes back.

Unfortunately, command-line access is not available.

* I suppose this could actually be a coincidence.

Comment: is PerlMagick an option?

Answer (score 1):

You can use convert's [debug option](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=dn96447fk9phu115lq9o4ssc51#debug) to find out what it's doing.

To capture all outputs of a shell command use [Capture::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Capture%3a%3aTiny) like this:

```
use Capture::Tiny 'capture';

my @command = qw( convert foo.jpg foo.gif );

my $return_code;
my ($stdout, $stderr) = capture {
    $return_code = system( @command );
};
```

`$stdout` and `$stderr` will contain what it says on the tin. `$return_code` will return the return code of the task itself, which is traditionally 0 when successful or a non-zero numerical value when an error happened.

Answer (score 0):

They may have no shell installed (think of perl/mod_perl being run in a chroot), such that backticks cannot be executed at all (since they involve calling `sh -c 'convert ...'`. Always check `$?` and `$!`.

Comment: Note that I tried system() as well, and note that this code worked just fine until very recently, and the client was told the change was to DNS only.

Comment: I just checked -- both backticks and system() work for a simple `ls` command, so they do have some kind of shell.

Comment: a plain "ls" does not show that /bin/sh exists.  perl handles simple cases internally, only using the real shell if there are metacharacters (like redirections)